# VS Code default browser

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, default-browser

I made VS Code default browser to be Google Chrome (selected `chrome` in `liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser`), but `live-server` opens Google Chrome only in case if I right-click on `.html` file, but if I type in console `live-server` it opens in the system-wide default browser. So how can I fix that? I want to open VS Code default browser from the console.

Comment: When you run it in the terminal it's not up to VS Code, it just uses the system default. Either change the system default, use the plugin instead of the command line or use the [documented](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server#usage-from-command-line) flag to override the browser.